# I/flutter (21647): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'User' has no instance getter 'password'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
//register.dart

    
    RaisedButton(onPressed:(){
  FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password
  ).then((signedInUser){
   UserManagement().storeNewUser(signedInUser.user, context);
  }).catchError((e){
    print(e);
  });
    } ,
    child: Text('Register'),
    ),



//usermanagement.dart

class UserManagement{
  storeNewUser(user , context){
    Firestore.instance.collection('/users').add({
      'email' : user.email,
      'password' : user.password,
    }).then((value) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/menupage');
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

*When i use signedInUser.user i get the error*

I/flutter (21647): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'User' has no instance getter 'password'

I/flutter (21647): Receiver: Instance of 'User'

I/flutter (21647): Tried calling: password

*I get the error below when i used signedInUser*

I/flutter (21647): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'UserCredential' has no instance getter 'email'.

I/flutter (21647): Receiver: Instance of 'UserCredential'

I/flutter (21647): Tried calling: email

*Someone please help me out with this*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'User' has no instance getter 'password'

Is telling you that the [User](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) class has not property called password.  In fact, Firebase Auth does not have a way of getting the user's password after the account is created.  That would be a security problem, and there is no "fix" or workaround.

As a matter of best practice, you're also not supposed to store password in your database, which is another security problem.  If you must really store a password, you should do that while you have it still in memory after the user typed it in.  But you really should design your app without having to know the user's password at all.  Firebase Auth handles it all securely for you so you don't accidentally make security mistakes.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i'm new to firebase so can you tell me what i should do exactly because i'm really confused right now .I can see my user in the authentication panel in firebase but nothing gets uploaded to the database.

Comment: I gave my recommendation in the answer.  If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i just used what you reccomended and it worked for me.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary to upvote and accept it as correct using the buttons to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

//I just removed the line `**'password' : user.password**` in usermanagement.dart

```
class UserManagement{
  storeNewUser(user , context){
    Firestore.instance.collection('/users').add({
      'email' : user.email,
    }).then((value) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/menupage');
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

Ijust removed the line 'password' : user.password

and used signedInUser.user instead of just signedInUser in register.dart.